# Convert HTML page to JPG

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am trying to get a html page to output to a jpg file with a fixed width and height. I have already tried many ways but no one seems to have the answer. I have tried scripts including php. Also tried Painty but that only supports h1 tags and I have css in the html page that needs to be turned into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,to Convert HTML page to JPG

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: That’s html to pdf